# ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password when migrating from TOMCAT to IBM Websphere

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, websphere, datasource

We are migrating a war file from TOMCAT to IBM Websphere 8.5.5 application server. It is working fine on TOMCAT, but throwing "invalid username/password logon denied" error in IBM WAS. I have correct datasource configured in web.xml and persistence.xml. I also checked with our server admin and he confirmed that the datasource is correct and able to test successfully using the same. Not sure if I need to add/change any configs here for IBM WAAS 8.5.5. Please advise.

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>Example datasource</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/exampleDS</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="sample">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/exampleDS</jta-data-source>
  <class>com.hibernate.test.Example</class>
  <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="XXXXXX"/>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
   </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Structure of the project:

```
ExampleRestService.war
  - WEB-INF/classes
    - com/hibernate/test/Resource
    - com/hibernate/test/Application
    - log4j.properties
  - WEB-INF/lib
    - hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
    - hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar
    - hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.1.Final.jar
    - hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
    - jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar
    - jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar
    - jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.jar
    - jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar
    - javassist-3.15.0.GA.jar
    - jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
    - jersey-apache-client-1.8.jar
    - jersey-atom-abdera-1.8.jar
    - jersey-client-1.8.jar
    - jersey-core-1.8.jar
    - jersey-guice-1.8.jar
    - jersey-multipart-1.8.jar
    - jersey-server-1.8.jar
    - jersey-simple-server-1.8.jar
    - jersey-spring-1.8.jar
    - jettison-1.2.jar
    - jettison-1.1.jar
    - jsr173_api.jar
    - jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
    - ojdbc6.jar
    - postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc3.jar
    - ExampleLibrary.jar
  - ExampleLibrary.jar/META-INF/Persistence.xml
  - web/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Update:
Adding stacktrcae

```
12/14/16 09:19:50.916    000000D2    com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp    SEVERE    com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[ServletAdaptor]: javax.persistence.QueryTimeoutException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1322)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1288)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1370)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    at com.dd.core.RequestHandler.handleRequest(RequestHandler.java:89)
    at com.hibernate.test.Resource.invokeExampleService(Resource.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1820)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1309)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:57)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 72000, Error Code = 1,017
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1018)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:497)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:433)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:950)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:639)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:662)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:560)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:311)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:486)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:174)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1365)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:2154)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1787)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1557)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1113)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2161)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1839)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3818)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3094)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:644)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Are you or the admin able to test the datasource using IBM WAS? There should be an option on the WAS Admin console GUI to test the datasource. The error suggests, it is username/password error.

Comment: Yes. Our admin confirmed that he is able to test the datasource.

Comment: Make sure that he has correct authentication alias in both - Container and Component auth alias set in the admin console. Also provide stacktrace with your actual exception from the SystemOut.log

Comment: Added stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have container managed authentication set up for the data source (or in the resource reference bindings) but don't have component managed authentication defined for the data source, that could lead to this problem occurring, because you would be able to look up the data source without a resource reference which wouldn't use container managed authentication. To use container managed authentication, you need to use the resource reference when looking up the data source.

Have you tried specifying the resource reference name for the data source in the persistent unit.  For example,

```
 <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/exampleDS</jta-data-source>
```

See:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_defjpadatasource.html

Also, you should confirm that your data source either has a default container managed authentication alias configured, or it specifies a container managed authentication alias in the resource reference bindings, and that the user/password are correct.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Changing jta datasource property from <jta-data-source>jdbc/exampleDS</jta-data-source> to <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/exampleDS</jta-data-source> in persistence xml made the difference.